# BeautyEye LaF JTextField in JPopupMenu is disabled

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I'm using the [BeautyEye Laf](https://github.com/JackJiang2011/beautyeye) for a Java Swing application. 
I'm setting a `JTextField` inside a `JPopupMenu`. The `JTextField` appears disabled no matter what I do. The code is a bit complicated but I've made this snippet that's easily testable

```
public static void main(String[] s)
throws Exception 
{
    BeautyEyeLNFHelper.frameBorderStyle = BeautyEyeLNFHelper.FrameBorderStyle.generalNoTranslucencyShadow;
    org.jb2011.lnf.beautyeye.BeautyEyeLNFHelper.launchBeautyEyeLNF();

    final JPopupMenu popupTable = new JPopupMenu();
    // find panel
    JLabel findLabel = new JLabel("Filter for:");
    findLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60, 20));
    final JTextField findTextField = new JTextField();
    findTextField.setColumns(10);

    final JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10, 0));
    container.add(findLabel);
    container.add(findTextField);

    popupTable.add(container);

    JButton button = new JButton("Action");

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    buttonPanel.add(button);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(popupTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(900, 800);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    button.addActionListener
    (
        new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                int x = (frame.getWidth() / 2);
                int y = (frame.getHeight() / 2);

                popupTable.show(frame, x, y);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

If I remove the `LaF` (comment the first two lines) everything works as expected. The `JTextField` is editable. I'm asking here first in hope that I'm doing something wrong. If this proves to be a bug I will post this as an issue on Github.

Comment: This is really an issue for the developer of the library, I recommend you raise a bug on github for them to take a look at it

Comment: Yes, I will do that. I was just hoping that I did something wrong and it's not a bug after all. I'm not very familiar with Swing so I thought asking here to try my luck.

Comment: I tried using the System Look and Feel and seems to work.  I think it has to do with the "type" of window which is created to show the popup, but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: Just to be clear, this is just a showcase. In the original code, the popup is added as a popup component to a table which is displayed after right click. I don't know if this helps or complicates things. But I believe it's the same behavior.

Comment: That's how I tested it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was a minor change in the library. From the author:

> You can find class
>   org.jb2011.lnf.beautyeye.ch7_popup.TranslucentPopupFactory source code
>   at line 416, change "setFocusableWindowState(false);" to
>   "setFocusableWindowState(true);" or just delete this line.